# iOS Metal double-buffering at 120 fps

Tags: ios, metal

Is there a way to get double-buffering at 120Hz (ProMotion) instead of triple buffering? I'm trying to minimize UI latency.

When I use Xcode's iOS Game template (which renders a rotating cube), I still get triple-buffering at 120hz, despite the trivial amount of work. It's double-buffered at 60hz.

To reproduce:

1. Create a new project in Xcode using File → New → Project
2. Select iOS → Game
3. Select Swift / Metal
4. In `GameViewController` add `mtkView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 120`
5. Product → Profile
6. Select Metal System Trace
7. Observe: triple buffering (3 colors for frames):

[image: Image showing triple buffering in Instruments]

Looking at the graph, it seems the GPU finishes well within the time required for double-buffering.

Here's a useful video to watch for some background: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/233/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps can control the max number Metal of drawables  [CAMetalLayer.maximumDrawableCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/2938720-maximumdrawablecount?language=objc).  Setting this to 2 will force double buffering (3 is the default).  Be aware that this makes it more likely [-[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/1478172-nextdrawable?language=objc) (or MTKView equivalents) will return nil, forcing you to drop a frame.

Comment: Looks like currently the maximum frame rate is halved for double-buffered Metal layers. For 60-fps devices it’s 30, for 120-fps ones it’s 60.